# Fix position for tranlate() while rotate() only in p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Have a class with methods that draws rectangular shapes with random lengths.

However, is unable to only do rotate() on the shapes without translating ( translate() ), which translate will make the shapes draw off the canvas.

So are there anyways to make it so no translation occurs while rotating?

*The code:*

```
class rect {

 constructor(range) {
   this.boundary = 100;

   this.x = random(this.boundary, width - this.boundary);
   this.y = random(this.boundary, height - this.boundary);
   this.xu = this.x + random(50, 200);
   this.yu = this.y + random(50, 200);

   this.range = range;
   this.limit = random(-range, range);

   this.rand_color1 = random(255);
   this.rand_color2 = random(255);
   this.rand_color3 = random(255);
 }

 custom_shapes() {   

   // how to make no translations occur while only perform rotation on shapes?
   translate(this.x-this.margin,this.y-this.margin);
   rotate(30);

   fill(this.rand_color1, this.rand_color2, this.rand_color3)
   quad(this.x, this.y, this.xu + this.limit, this.y, this.xu, this.yu, this.x, this.yu + this.limit);
   }

 }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking but for rotation it often makes sense to translate a figure to the center, rotate and then translate back to where it needs to display in order to get the figure to rotate about its center. If this is your case take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406447/1978785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your rectangular is going of the screen when rotating, it's rotating around x = 0, y= 0 point, so i guess you could do something like:

```
push() //push and pop acts as a way to "seperate" any style and translate and so on...
rectMode(CENTER)         // basically the middle of the rect = x , y
translate(this.x,this.y) // **OR** translate(this.x - this.rectSizeX / 2, this.y - this.rectSizeY / 2) 
//quad()                 // if you're not using the rectMode()
pop() // also you'll have to fill() and so on in here i believe, not too sure
```

also if you know it's allways going to be a long or tall square, you can just use rect(x,y,xSize,ySize) // if think it's the size anyways

If you just want to separate translate() in general, just put push() and pop() around it...

Oh yeah and translate() basically just makes whatever x and y you give it into 0,0... Dunno if i said that already i'm just editing this the next day.